# How to not execute .js file in a shell

Tags: shell, firebase, firebase-tools

While I want to run `firebase` cli in my folder to deploy and serve, shell automatically execute `firebase.js` file in the folder.

This causes Microsoft JScript compilation error.

This kind of error did not happen in a mac but this happens in windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily executed `firebase` cli by specifying package location

`c:\Users\$USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase deploy`